# How to embed images in Haddock documentation

Tags: haskell, documentation, haddock

How can I embed images within local [Haddock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haddock_%28software%29) documentation?

I see for example [the `lens` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) just uses external links to images, but I'd like to store the images locally.

(This question is very similar to [an (unanswered) question on the mailing list](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2011-December/097898.html)).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to store your image locally you can:

```
-- A longer description of the package.
description: Some haskell package description.

    <<file:///home/user/your_image.png>>
```

Result:

[image]

If you don't want or can't add image by relative path, just put image name without full path:

`<<your_image.png>>`

In this case, your image must be in the `project/docs` directory.

Comment: I can't find any way to hack this to get a relative path, though -- so it's brittle because it assumes a directory where the documentation will be used on a user's drive. Right?

Comment: Yes, you're right. If you can't get a relative path to your images, you can also add just ```<<Haskell-Logo-Variation.png>>``` and than Haskell-Logo-Variation.png image must be in the project's doc directory.

Comment: Perfect! That's just what I was looking for. Can you add that to your answer? Note also that if your image is in e.g. `docs/images/`, you can reference it with `<<images/some_img.jpg>>`

Comment: Has anybody figured out how to hook into cabal to automatically copy the picture into the documentation directory?

Comment: @lpsmith: If you already have your docs directory with the images in it, `cabal-install` should just put the documentation in with the images.

Comment: (At least for the documentation in the package directory)

Answer (score 10):

As explained in that mailing list thread you reference, one option is to use a [data URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) to inline images into your documentation.  It makes the source itself somewhat unpleasant to read (since it is interspersed with large blobs of base64-encoded data), though using Haddock's [named chunks](http://www.haskell.org/haddock/doc/html/ch03s05.html) can help, by putting all the images in named chunks at the end of the file.  For a real-world example of this approach, see the [Haddock documentation for the circle-packing package](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/circle-packing/0.1.0.2/doc/html/Optimisation-CirclePacking.html).

Comment: It's odd that it shouldn't let you refer to data-files in your Cabal package. o_o

Comment: I don't think Haddock knows anything about Cabal or even ghc-pkg, does it?

Comment: The data url trick is pretty neat. That might fix the performance problems we get fetching from the wiki in `lens`. (We changed the links in `lens.cabal` file to point off to `imgur`, because it doesn't have cache disabling problems.)

Comment: Interestingly, if you try to make an image that is too much bigger than the one from the `circle-packing` package, haddock dies with a stack overflow. =/

Answer (score 9):

As explained in [a blog post by Ian Ross](http://www.skybluetrades.net/blog/posts/2014/02/21/haddock-images-on-haskell.html) you could use `extra-doc-files` cabal option to bundle extra files into the documentation.